# TaskRouter: Leaving a queue

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter

I'm building a call center and I need a way for people to "get out of the queue" to leave a voicemail **OR** be redirected to an emergency contact. 
I want them to have that option every 2 minutes or so (This is a medical hotline).

The best I could think of is using a `waitUrl` on top of the `<Enqueue>` verb, which periodically offers the caller to press 1 for voicemail or 2 for an emergency.

If I just needed one or another I could simply use `<Leave />` and have the verbs after the `<Enqueue>` redirect somewhere or capture a recording.

Unfortunately since I `<Gather>` (digits 1 or 2) during the `waitUrl` I need the `<Leave />` verb to take me to a specific URL/Action based on the digits - which is impossible.

Any creative solutions to this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than using `<Leave>` when you get the result of the `<Gather>` you could [use the REST API to redirect the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#update-a-call-resource).

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, it does! For anyone who follows - it is also mandatory to "cancel" the initial task as looks like the redirect causes the call to get "detached" from the task and will remain in "reserved" state indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the task (I don't use TaskRouter a lot personally). Glad this helped.